# is there a way to apply a background color through css at the tr level?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to apply a background color through CSS at the TR level?  I can apply it at the TD level like this:

```
    .my-td{
        background-color: #E8E8E8;
        background:#E8E8E8;
    }
```

However, the background color doesn't seem to get applied when I attempt to apply the background color at the TR level like this:

```
    .my-tr{
        background-color: #E8E8E8;
        background:#E8E8E8;
    }
```

Is there a CSS trick to making this work or does CSS not natively support this for some reason?

Comment: Your code is okay. It seems like tr css rule is over-ruled by some other css.

Comment: It works on some browsers, but the most common (and supported) way is to color the TD inside the TR. Like .my-tr td{...}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, applying a background color on a table row works.

Here's an example:

```css
.odd {
  background-color: pink;
}

.even {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td>a1</td>
    <td>a2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td>b1</td>
    <td>b2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="odd">
    <td>c1</td>
    <td>c2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="even">
    <td>d1</td>
    <td>d2</td>
  </tr>  
</table>
```

Something else must be interfering with your colours or there's a particular browser issue that you're encountering if this isn't working for you.